# Facing issue while scrolling down to the bottom of the page imacros/javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, scroll, html, imacros

I'm using iMacros v9.0.3 on Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bit) in Windows 8 x64

I'm attempting to scroll down to the bottom the page in imacros and I'm using the code

```
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBY(0,20000)
```

the code is working fine but the problem is the step unnecessarily waiting for 60s

[image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DDphJvjUAAAq-k0.jpg]

my question is how to skip the 60 sec timeout? Or any other way to solve this problem and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the 'Event mode' command like this:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* KEY=35
```